# Recognizing a possibly obfuscated character encoding used in a database

Tags: encodings

I downloaded [デジタル大辞泉](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/%e3%83%87%e3%82%b8%e3%82%bf%e3%83%ab%e5%a4%a7%e8%be%9e%e6%b3%89/9wzdncrdn6fn) trial from Microsoft Store to try it out. The interface was not very good in my opinion, so I thought that maybe it is possible to extract the dictionary and convert it to another dictionary format.

I opened `Assets\db\resource_A` with [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/), and found some text matching the user interface, but there was a problem:

[image: daijisen]

Only the Latin alphabet are the same between these two. Here's some raw data I collected:

```
db,real
IT㘠敹嶋,IT・数学
冠嶋,区学
凹嶋,地学
煄璲,生物
璲灏㘠再嶋,物理・化学
煄楠,生活
煠嘆,画像
捹謆运劻誌,新規追加語
噷貌,品詞
㐥㐺㈆㐍,ことわざ
囤嶅猄誌,四字熟語
㈢㈀㈢㘮誌,カタカナ語
ABC畓垁,ABC略号
嶣誌,季語
難誒誌,難読語
煺湕㘠䣦掓,用法・下接
捇嶋,文学
杓懚垩,日本史
䣍畞垩,世界史
```

I can see that for example 学 corresponds to 嶋 in the database, but when I checked if there was a set code point shift or something, the output was pretty messy. Here's some data on that (db, correct, db hex, correct hex, db-correct):

```
I   T   㘠   敹   嶋
I   T   ・   数   学
0x49    0x54    0x3620  0x6579  0x5d8b
0x49    0x54    0x30fb  0x6570  0x5b66
0x0 0x0 0x525   0x9 0x225

冠   嶋
区   学
0x51a0  0x5d8b
0x533a  0x5b66
-0x19a  0x225

凹   嶋
地   学
0x51f9  0x5d8b
0x5730  0x5b66
-0x537  0x225

煄   璲
生   物
0x7144  0x74b2
0x751f  0x7269
-0x3db  0x249

璲   灏   㘠   再   嶋
物   理   ・   化   学
0x74b2  0x704f  0x3620  0x518d  0x5d8b
0x7269  0x7406  0x30fb  0x5316  0x5b66
0x249   -0x3b7  0x525   -0x189  0x225

煄   楠
生   活
0x7144  0x6960
0x751f  0x6d3b
-0x3db  -0x3db

煠   嘆
画   像
0x7160  0x5606
0x753b  0x50cf
-0x3db  0x537

捹   謆   运   劻   誌
新   規   追   加   語
0x6379  0x8b06  0x8fd0  0x52bb  0x8a8c
0x65b0  0x898f  0x8ffd  0x52a0  0x8a9e
-0x237  0x177   -0x2d   0x1b    -0x12

噷   貌
品   詞
0x5677  0x8c8c
0x54c1  0x8a5e
0x1b6   0x22e

㐥   㐺   ㈆   㐍
こ   と   わ   ざ
0x3425  0x343a  0x3206  0x340d
0x3053  0x3068  0x308f  0x3056
0x3d2   0x3d2   0x177   0x3b7

囤   嶅   猄   誌
四   字   熟   語
0x56e4  0x5d85  0x7304  0x8a8c
0x56db  0x5b57  0x719f  0x8a9e
0x9 0x22e   0x165   -0x12

㈢   ㈀   ㈢   㘮   誌
カ   タ   カ   ナ   語
0x3222  0x3200  0x3222  0x362e  0x8a8c
0x30ab  0x30bf  0x30ab  0x30ca  0x8a9e
0x177   0x141   0x177   0x564   -0x12

A   B   C   畓   垁
A   B   C   略   号
0x41    0x42    0x43    0x7553  0x5781
0x41    0x42    0x43    0x7565  0x53f7
0x0 0x0 0x0 -0x12   0x38a

嶣   誌
季   語
0x5da3  0x8a8c
0x5b63  0x8a9e
0x240   -0x12

難   誒   誌
難   読   語
0x96e3  0x8a92  0x8a8c
0x96e3  0x8aad  0x8a9e
0x0 -0x1b   -0x12

煺   湕   㘠   䣦   掓
用   法   ・   下   接
0x717a  0x6e55  0x3620  0x48e6  0x6393
0x7528  0x6cd5  0x30fb  0x4e0b  0x63a5
-0x3ae  0x180   0x525   -0x525  -0x12

捇   嶋
文   学
0x6347  0x5d8b
0x6587  0x5b66
-0x240  0x225

杓   懚   垩
日   本   史
0x6753  0x61da  0x57a9
0x65e5  0x672c  0x53f2
0x16e   -0x552  0x3b7

䣍   畞   垩
世   界   史
0x48cd  0x755e  0x57a9
0x4e16  0x754c  0x53f2
-0x549  0x12    0x3b7
```

If you want to see a pattern, there are some characters that are from the same distance of their corresponding character in the database (okay maybe it's just the birthday problem though):

### -0x12

- 0x8a9e
- 0x7565
- 0x63a5

### -0x3db

- 0x751f
- 0x6d3b
- 0x753b

Also the distance between the real character and the database character isn't very large, none of them are in the 0x1000's.

[Here's](https://www.google.ch/patents/US20100131518) some patent about character set based obfuscation. Not sure if it's in any way related to this one.

Is this some common character encoding or am I looking at an obfuscated database?

Comment: I don't know what encoding you used to paste your sample data, but maybe try EUC-JP or Shift-JIS.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I exported the one that should be "IT・数学" and it's `49 54 e3 98 a0 e6 95 b9 e5 b6 8b`. Python's shift-jis and euc-jp fail to decode it but utf-8 works, it just outputs the wrong characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a Store app, most likely it's a .net executable so it shouldn't be too difficult to decompile it and see what it does with the data from the database. I expect they do apply some encryption or obfuscation on the data but it does not seem to be something obvious from your samples.